# objective c singleton return nil

Tags: objective-c, xcode, singleton

I have singleton to use websocket connection, when _srWebSocket = nil, will returned new _srWebSocket, but when _srWebSocket connected, will returned nil

```
@interface SocketManager : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, weak) SRWebSocket *srWebSocket;

+ (SocketManager *) sharedInstance;

@end

@implementation SocketManager

@synthesize srWebSocket = _srWebSocket;

+ (SocketManager *) sharedInstance {
    static SocketManager *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[SocketManager alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}
- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        NSLog(@"In SocketKeeperSingleton init");
    }
    return self;
}
- (SRWebSocket *) srWebSocket {
    if (!_srWebSocket || _srWebSocket.readyState == SR_CLOSED) {
        _srWebSocket = [[SRWebSocket alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"wss://...:8000"]];
        [_srWebSocket open];
    }
    return _srWebSocket;
}

@end
Call singleton 
srWebSocket = [SocketManager sharedInstance].srWebSocket;
```

Comment: I think you need to write else part of "if (!_srWebSocket || _srWebSocket.readyState == SR_CLOSED) {
        _srWebSocket = [[SRWebSocket alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"wss://...:8000"]];
        [_srWebSocket open];
    }", because when both condition are wrong.

Comment: I need to use opened connection

Comment: Hey @Qwerty bro where are you calling this method `srWebSocket `

Comment: You are just accessing `srWebSocket` property its okay but you dont have getting initialized object.

Comment: @Mukesh SRWebSocket * srWebSocket = [SocketManager sharedInstance].srWebSocket;

Comment: I have added answer check it now.

Comment: @Qwerty bro can you add `static SocketManager *sharedInstance = nil;` just bellow `@implementation SocketManager` this line & remove from `sharedInstance` method.

Comment: @Mukesh not helped

Comment: I think you are doing wrong elsewhere. Because upto my knowledge everything should have to work.

Comment: @Mukesh anyway thanks for help

Comment: Welcome :) You can learn more about iOS Singleton from here   https://www.raywenderlich.com/46988/ios-design-patterns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `srWebSocket` method call,

**First way,**

Declare one method in singleton.h file

```
-(void) doInitialSetupOnLaunch;
```

Add this method somewhere in your singleton.m file,

```
-(void) doInitialSetupOnLaunch {
   //Put your initialized code i mean you can call your method from here & define your properties here.

 _srWebSocket = [self srWebSocket];
}

- (SRWebSocket *) srWebSocket {
    if (!_srWebSocket || _srWebSocket.readyState == SR_CLOSED) {
        _srWebSocket = [[SRWebSocket alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"wss://...:8000"]];
        [_srWebSocket open];
    }
    return _srWebSocket;
}
```

Call it from somewhere,best way you can call from appDelegate.m

Now you are ready to access it by property,

```
Call singleton 
srWebSocket = [SocketManager sharedInstance].srWebSocket;
```

**Or Second way**

```
SRWebSocket * srWebSocket = [[SocketManager sharedInstance] srWebSocket];
```

Comment: -(void) doInitialSetupOnLaunch {
   _srWebSocket = [[SRWebSocket alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"wss://message.api.sendway.com:8000"]];
} like this, sorry I'm android developer with objective c I'm working first time

Comment: Its okay bro :) Once you get 15+ reputation accept & up my answer.

Comment: I need use opened connection

Comment: Since, you have to call  `[_srWebSocket open];` method.You are new Forget first way you can just use this one `SRWebSocket * srWebSocket = [[SocketManager sharedInstance] srWebSocket];'

Comment: In first controller `SRWebSocket * srWebSocket = [[SocketManager sharedInstance] srWebSocket] return new SRWebSocket  and connection was open, but when I  `SRWebSocket * srWebSocket = [[SocketManager sharedInstance] srWebSocket] retrun SRWebSocket nil, because it was opened

Comment: Friend , It should have to work still Can you change property srWebSocket weak to retain & check if it is working.

Comment: I'm sorry, last question what should be here -(void) doInitialSetupOnLaunch {
   //Put your initialized code i mean you can call your method from here & define your properties here.

 _srWebSocket = [self srWebSocket];
}

Comment: Nothing more in  that method. If you have added this code its already initialized your `_srWebSocket` property.

Comment: where should i call this method doInitialSetupOnLaunch?

Comment: Add this line  `[[SocketManager sharedInstance] doInitialSetupOnLaunch];` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method of AppDelegate.m

Comment: thanks for your help, but still don't work, will be find solution myself

Comment: AppDelegate
[[SocketManager sharedInstance] doInitialSetupOnLaunch];
    SRWebSocket *socket = [[SocketManager sharedInstance] srWebSocket];
    socket.delegate = self; - here ok
but ViewContoller
SRWebSocket * srWebSocket = [[SocketManager sharedInstance] srWebSocket]; - nil

Answer (score 1):

because you have write 'static SocketManager *sharedInstance = nil;' in shareInstance Method .
when this method call every time they send nil .

```
 + (SocketManager *) sharedInstance {
static SocketManager *sharedInstance = nil;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    sharedInstance = [[SocketManager alloc] init];
});
return sharedInstance;
```

}

write down this line outside shareInstance method "static SocketManager *sharedInstance = nil;"